# In Blender 3D, when I try a fluid simulation, the fluid goes through the mesh rather than colliding with it

Tags: mac, simulation, blender, fluid

I set up a fluid simulation using this tutorial:
http://xedium3d.com/tutorials/fluid/
I know that this tutorial is for an older version of Blender, but the buttons and controls are still right there. I made sure to make my object an obstacle, but when I 'bake' the simulation, the liquid falls right through the object.

I have played with the variables a lot and tried pushing all of the buttons in different configurations.

I think that this is happening because my collision object is a plane that was sub-divided into a grid. How can i make the liquid flow across my grid rather than through it?

Answer (score 1):

In Blender any object that is used as an obstacle for a fluid simulation needs to have a thickness. So yes, you are correct the fluid flowing through your obstacle is a result of it being just a plane. Extrude a thickness and you should see your desired result.